# c++ can i reuse class member's interface as interface, just like reuse base class's member

Tags: c++

sometimes we need combine multiple class as a new class, see below:

```
class A
{
public:
    void SomeHandle();
};
class B;
class C;
```

each of them provide some useful function,then i need a new class to provide a union of them, so i would write as below:

```
class Combine
{
public:
    void Combine::SomeHandle();
private:
 A objA;
 B objB;
 C objC;
};
```

but then i have to write lots of code to rediect call to Combine to corresponding object, like:

```
void Combine::SomeHandle()
{
    objA.SomeHandle();
}
```

is there any simpler way expect macro to do that?

Comment: the more direct equivalent of all three classes combined would be to have `A`,`B` and `C` members public. When there is a reason to make them `private` then `void Combine::SomeHandle()` is more than just calling `objA.SomeHandle()`. In other words, when `Combine::SomeHandle` is only calling `objA.SomeHandle()` without doing anything else, then why not make `objA` public?

Comment: the question is not clear, why do you need to make them private? Why is there no `getA` method on `Combine` ?

Comment: I know what you mean, but this is just a simple example,  in actually, it may be server part so i would not let client  to know the detail implement of it

Comment: exactly "not letting the client know the implementation details". This implies that the interface of `Combine` is substantially different from just repeating all methods of its members. The problem is that the details that determine the solution are left out from your code

Comment: Of course it's not  simply repeating all methods of its members, some of them would do some extra handle, or just a new treatment, but each member calss would have few function can do the whole thing, many a little makes a mickle， so i would need to write lots of code like above

Comment: How you detect which one combine is needed when user call ``` combineObject.SomeHandle(); ``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "Inheritance"?

```
class A
{
public:
   void someHandle();
};

class B:public A
{...
};
```

allows you to write

```
B someB;
someB.someHandle();
```

`class B` "inherits" all interfaces from `class A`.

It's a very, very basic feature of OOP.

Comment: i know inherits can do this, but there could be many class members and i would try to avoid Multiple inheritance， besides, in many case inherits is not a good idea in logical